# Calling asp.net web service from iOS application crash when data contains ampersands?

Tags: ios, web-services, nsmutableurlrequest

I have an application which actually calling asp.net web service but when I transfer data with `&` it stop working. Like below jsonString have first_name which have "Pranav &" so as this stage when I call service with converting it in asciistringencoding it generate error because of ascii convert it like

```
&quotPranav &&quot
```

with finding two ampersands it stop working

```
NSString * jsonString = @"{"home_phone":"123","GroupId":"GP00000099","first_name":"Pranav &","city":"df","last_name":"Purohit","state":"sl","email":"pjp@gmail.com","member_Id":"GM00008513"}";
NSString * post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"jsonText=%@", jsonString];
NSLog(@"%@",post);
NSData * postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
NSString * postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest * request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myweburl.com/mywebservice.asmx/mymethod"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSURLConnection * conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer, when you embed **&** replace it with **\u0026**